# Tokenizer efficiency question

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, tokenize

I'm writing a compiler front end for a project and I'm trying to understand what's the best method of tokenize the source code.
I can't choose between two ways:

1) the tokenizer read all tokens:

```
bool Parser::ReadAllTokens()
{
  Token token;
  while( m_Lexer->ReadToken( &token ) )
  {
    m_Tokens->push_back( token );
    token.Reset(); // reset the token values..
  }

  return !m_Tokens->empty();
}
```

and then the parsing phase begins, operating on the m_`Tokens` list. In this way the methods getNextToken(), peekNextToken() and ungetToken() are relatively easy to implement by iterator, and the parsing code is well written and clear ( not broken by getNextToken() i.e. :

```
 getNextToken();
 useToken();
 getNextToken();
 peekNextToken();
 if( peeked is something )
  ungetToken();
 ..
 ..
```

)

2) the parsing phase begins and when needed, the token is created and used ( the code seems not so clear )

What's the best method??and why??and the efficiency??
thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, compiler construction classes teach you to read tokens, one by one, as you parse. The reason for that, is that back in the days, memory resources were scarce. You had kilobytes to your disposal, and not gigabytes as you do today.

Having said that, I don't mean to recommend you to read all tokens in advance, and then parse from your list of tokens. Input is of arbitrary size. If you hog too much memory, the system will become slow. Since it looks like you only need one token in the lookahead, I'd read one at a time from the input stream. The operating system will buffer and cache the input stream for you, so it'll be fast enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use something like [Boost::Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/preface.html) to tokenise. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

Your method (1) is generally overkill - it is not required to tokenize an entire file prior parsing it.

A good way to go is to implement a buffered tokenizer, which will store in a list the tokens that were poke or unget, and which will consume the element of this list on "get" or read tokens from the file when the list gets empty (a la FILE*).

Answer (score 1):

The first method is better, as you can then also understand the code 3 month later...

Comment: There would be little or no difference for the actual parser, and the lexer would be marginally more complex. Marginally. Using buffered streams shouldn't be a mystery to any programmer, and thus peek() (or whatever your stream mechanism's preferred name is) should be quite easy to remember, even years from now...